# Handling Ajax response with success and without failure

Tags: angularjs

The below code has both success and failure handling

```
jQuery.ajax({

        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
        success: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Error';
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        },
    });

    $(":input").val('');
    return false;
```

However we are not following the above...We are following as below

```
jQuery.ajax({

        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.responseType == 'success') {
                 // success
            }
            if(data.responseType == 'failure') {
                 // failure
            }
        }
    });

    $(":input").val('');
    return false;
```

Is our approach is the correct or wrong approach ??

Basically every response will be success and show error message based on the response type

Please advise. We need to follow the best practice

Answer (score 0):

data. responseType doesn't return a 'success' or 'failure'. It is contains an enumerated value which represents the type of response coming back to you like text, json, arrayBuffer etc..

Hence in the second code block both if statements will be exceuted to be false and nothing will be done with the response received.

Comment: Sorry..i meant we are returning a customized Response Object which has the variable responseType......Forget to mention it...Example Respone class with variables responseType as String, ......

Comment: There might be confusions in ajax.. success and failure events... Jquery success event is triggered when the request was successful and the data received from server is without error. When a request is received by server it processes it and sends back a response but in the case of any run time expections happened at server or any connection problem within the channel the will be unable to process data and does not return a response to the client and when such things happen the failure event is triggered... When such exceptions happens the server won't be able to update your custom property

Comment: business error - user id doesn't exist. non-business error - NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Ok when confronting client errors server responds with a error status of 4xx status codes depending on the error caused by the client so called business error. In that case you can handle the error in your client side using jQuery. ajaxSetup something similiar to this              $.ajaxSetup({ error: function(xhr){ alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText); } });... Google $.ajaxSetup for more information

Comment: Prithivi thanks for the comment...Can u share a good code to follow as a template....it would be helpful...else paste any code from your application for better understanding and implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with the first approach because 
Whether you are using raw JS or a library to implement this functionality, you'll have access to the state of the request i.e. whether the request was successful; met with an error and finally whether it has been completed.

Make proper use of these events and their respective callbacks to manipulate the UI for a better user experience. For example, if the request was unsuccessful, you'd want to update the user interface to reflect that their changes weren't successful while if it was successful, you'd want to tell them so. Don't keep the user waiting!

With jQuery, you'd make use of the success and error callbacks. You also get other callbacks such as complete and beforeSend to be invoked for apporopriate use.

```
$.ajax({
        //Other code
           success: function(msg)
        {
            // Update the UI here to reflect that the request was successful.
            doSomethingClever();
        },
        error: function(msg)
        {
            // Update the UI here to reflect that the request was unsuccessful
            doSomethingMoreClever();
        },
        complete: function(msg)
        {
            // Update the UI here to reflect completion
            doSomethingEvenMoreClever();
        }
});
```

take a look at [this](http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/25)

Comment: Thanks..If i go with the first approach...How to differentiate business and non-business errors. Do we need to sent status code differently for business and non-business error ?? How to handle runtime exception ? Shall we catch the run time exception and change the status code and consider as business exception...We should never redirect to error page as the whole page would be lost for the user in any case....ex: NullPointer or RuntimException etc.,....Please advise

Comment: so basically as a best practice in web development you need to handle all the error code and status from backend itself. because whenever there is an error in ajax call you should show an appropriate message to the user. which is a main important thing while debugging also it will be easier in case of internal server errors. make the most use of angularjs for frontend use in UX.  considering your example. I didn't understand what do you mean by business and non-business errors. one more suggestion if you are using angularjs don't use jquery with it .. you can google more about it.

Comment: business error - user id doesn't exist. non-business error - NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: so basically you need to handle all this at server level . after an ajax is done and a request comes to server check if the request is valid like userid exist or no. check compile time error like a null pointer. if all of it is done and request and response are successful you can show success message, but if there is the business error you can be sent the response to frontend using a different status code and handle it on the frontend. also if there is non-business error sent status code different and show service is temporary down in frontend.

Comment: make sure use the same status code for all server calls. hope this helps

Comment: Can you please share some good sample code which does this??? I appreciate your wonderful comment and need your help for a code snippet to implement it

Comment: you can easily get this type of example code on the internet. thank you for your appreciation, if you feel this helped you don't forget to mark this as a helpful answer so that it will be useful for others too.

Comment: Can u get me an example...As you can help me with the right one

Comment: Also, for non-business error instead of service down..can we capture and show as business errors. what would be the usual problem if we are doing it?

Comment: so here is the example for you https://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/AGpP5/ . to handle business error you can set this message from server side itself and can display it on screen no need to handle it from the frontend. as a system architecture, i suggest you error handling is a big and important task . and it should be handled from server side itself.

Comment: you mean sent a response code which is equivalent to error so that error will be thrown in the front end..is that right ???